# What is the relation between custodial symmetry and $m_W = m_Z \cos \theta_W$?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, higgs, beyond-the-standard-model

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Custodial_symmetry), we can read that custodial symmetry is responsible for keeping $m_W = m_Z \cos \theta_W$ in the SM. However, in 2HDM, the most general scalar potential doesn't have custodial symmetry (am I right?). Still, in every 2HDM we have $m_W = m_Z \cos \theta_W$, even in those without custodial symmetry.

What is wrong here? Why is custodial symmetry responsible for $m_W = m_Z \cos \theta_W$ in the SM while in other models (like in some 2HDM) we have $m_W = m_Z \cos \theta_W$ without custodial symmetry?

Comment: Refs [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.5228) and [2](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0703051) haven't helped you?

Comment: They have, thank you. However, I still don't understand something. [This](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.5228.pdf) ref says between eqs 1.5 and 1.6 that "it is the invariance of $|D_\mu \phi|^2$ with respect to $SU(2)_{\mathrm{diag}}$ that insures $\rho = 1$ at tree-level." But in some 2HDM the symmetry under $SU(2)_{\mathrm{diag}}$ is not preserved and we still have $\rho = 1$. How does that happen?

Comment: Not being a model-builder, I don't know these models...

Answer (score 0):

You are right that the general 2HDM doesnt have a custodial symmetry.  However, the 2HDM having only scalar doublets it respects $\rho=1$ at tree level.

In fact, only very few scalar representations under the electroweak gauge group preserve the relation $\rho=1$ at tree level. This can be seen from an explicit expression that can be derived for $\rho$ at tree level with arbitrary scalar representations (see for instance page 9 [here](https://indico.cern.ch/event/680421/contributions/3096169/attachments/1697103/2731972/Shinya_KANEMURA_Electroweak_and_Higgs_physics-2.pdf)).

In the case of the 2HDM, the custodial violating terms in the scalar potential only contribute to $\rho$ at the one-loop level, see for instance Sec. 4 in [arXiv:1011.6188](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.6188).